# Approximating continuous positive functions

Tags: polynomials, approximation

Let $f:[0,1]^n\to (0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. The stone-weierstrass theorem gives $\forall \epsilon >0$ we have a polynomial $p$ s.t $||f-p||_{\infty}<\epsilon$. I was wondering if we can approximate $f$ with a non-linear functions of the following form:
 $$p=\sum_{j=1}^k\alpha_j\prod_{i=1}^nx_i^{\beta_{i,j}}$$
 where $\alpha_i,\beta_{i,j}\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $\alpha_i>0$ and $\beta_{i,j}>0.$

Is this possible?

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial, then $\beta_{i,j}$ are non-negative.  Did you want to allow for non-polynomials with $-1 < \beta_{i,j} < 0$?  And if so, did you want to keep the same domain to evaluate $\|f-p\|_\infty$ (it just seems weird you're specifying $\beta_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ and also calling $p$ a polynomial)

Comment: you are right. $\beta_{i,j}>0$ and I should have called them non-linear functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your polynomials of interest are those with all positive coefficients, but such functions are monotonic increasing on the unit interval.  Hence they cannot approximate e.g. a decreasing function.

Comment: Thank you Yly. I will apply it for monotonic examples.

Comment: @Asker to be clear, it is not true that any monotonic function can be approximated by your class of polynomials either.  For instance, all such polynomials have monotonic derivatives and are convex as well, which is not true of all monotonic functions.